# Discriminants of quartic fields are $k$-power free for some $k$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a quadratic number field. Then the discriminant of $K$ is either $d$ or $4d$ for some squarefree integer $d$, so the discriminant is never divisible by an odd square. I am wondering if this can be generalised to number fields of higher degree. In particular, is it the case that there is some $k$ such that the discriminant of a quartic number field is never divisible by an odd $k$th power?

I have checked every quartic number field in the [PARI database](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/numberfields/), and none of them has discriminant divisible by an odd ninth power, so maybe the conjecture holds with $k=9$. This is not particularly strong evidence, though, since the database only contains quartic fields with discriminant below $1,000,000$, and such discriminants can never be divisible by any odd ninth power apart from $3^9$.

This seems like a question whose answer might be well-known. Does anybody know?

Comment: Do you like p-adic algebraic extensions? The idea is to find an upper bound for $v_p(Disc(L/\Bbb{Q}_p))$ whenever $[L:\Bbb{Q}_p]\le 4$.

Comment: @reuns such an upper bound certainly exists for a given $p$ (and actually that's enough for my purposes;  I'm happy for the bound to depend on $p$), since there are finitely many extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$ of given degree. I'm not sure how that enables me to to solve the original problem though. Is there some way of expressing the discriminant of a number field in terms of the discriminants of its $p$-adic completions?

Comment: Yes $Disc(K)$ relates directly to the discriminants of its completions. The upper bound won't depend on $p$ because for $p\ge 5$, $\sigma(\pi_L)/\pi_L$ is known from its reduction $\bmod \pi_L$ where $\sigma(\pi_L)$ is a $\Bbb{Q}_p$-conjugate of $\pi_L$.