# For a quartic number field $K$, can we choose $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $v_p([\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]])$ is bounded?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This question follows on from my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371618/discriminants-of-quartic-fields-are-k-power-free-for-some-k?noredirect=1#comment9133722_4371618). Fix a prime $p$. My question is: does there exist a positive integer $k$ such that for any $S_4$-quartic number field $K$, there is an algebraic integer $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $v_p([\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]) \leq k$?

Having searched the [PARI database](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/numberfields/), the largest $v_p([\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]])$ I can find is $7$, but obviously this does not constitute very strong evidence for the claim. I tried generalising the ideas @reuns used in the comments of my linked question, but I didn't get very far, because $\alpha$ might have arbitrarily large discriminants with respect to the completions (if it's even true that you can use completions to compute the discriminants of elements, which I haven't checked).

Comment: The answer is yes (for fields of degree $d$). The point is that there are only finitely many possibilities for $K_p:=K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p$ which shows that $k$ is bounded in terms of $p$. But you can take $k=0$ for $p \ge d$;  $K_p$ is a product of fields so choose $\alpha$ so that it generates the ring of integers of each field and the residual images are distinct in each case (possible when $p \ge d$). This reduces the quartic field case to the cases $p=2$ and $p=3$. I imagine the worst case is $p=2$ and when $K_2 = (\mathbf{Q}_2)^4$.

Comment: @user994373 I don't understand why it suffices to consider the problem locally. In fact, I'm not even sure what it would mean to consider this problem locally. Could you please provide a bit more detail?

Comment: The local problem is: Let $K_p$ be a product of finite extensions of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ with $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbf{Q_p}}(K_p) = d$, and let $A_p$ denote the ring of integers of $K_p$ (which is the product of the ring of integers of the corresponding fields). Then minimize the index of $\mathbf{Z}_p[\alpha_p]$ inside $A_p$. This will be bounded in terms of $d$ (because there are only finitely many $K_p$ and it will be one for $p \ge d$.

Comment: For number fields $K$ with ring of integers $A$, first find $\alpha_p \in A_p$, and then find an $\alpha \in A$ which approximates $\alpha_p$ sufficiently well. Then the $p$-power index of $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ in $A$ will equal the index of $\mathbf{Z}_p[\alpha]$ in $A$ which will equal the index of $\mathbf{Z}_p[\alpha_p]$ in $A$ if $\alpha$ is close enough to $\alpha_p$. This reduces the problem to a local computation. This should be more than enough detail if you know enough about local fields which you need to study for any serious study of number fields.

Comment: @user994373 thanks for the details, I understand almost all of it. The one part I'm still not quite seeing is why $[A : \mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha_p]] = [A : \mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]]$ for $\alpha$ close to $\alpha_p$. Regarding your last sentence, one of the aims of my current project is to reach sufficient familiarity with local fields for serious study, so I'm not quite there yet. Is there any chance you could explain why we have $[A : \mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha_p]] = [A : \mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]]$, or maybe point me to a reference?

Comment: Basic Hint: if $\mathbf{Z}_p[\alpha_p]$ has finite index in $A_p$, then it contains $p^m A_p$ for some $m$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it only for the tamely ramified primes $p\ge 5$.

Factorize in (at most $4$) prime ideals $$pO_K=\prod_j P_j^{e_j}$$

$$O_K\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}_p=
\varprojlim O_K/(p^n)=\varprojlim O_K/(\prod_j P_j^{e_j n})=\prod_j O_{K,P_j}$$
where $O_{K,P_j}=\varprojlim O_K/P_j^n$ is the completion at $P_j$.
Next
$$p^{v_p(Disc(O_K))}\Bbb{Z}_p=Disc(O_K\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}_p)\Bbb{Z}_p=(\prod_j Disc(O_{K,P_j}))\Bbb{Z}_p=p^{\sum_j v_p(Disc(O_{K,P_j}))}\Bbb{Z}_p$$
(think to $Disc(O_K)$ as $\det(Tr(a_ia_l))$ where $a_i$ is any $\Bbb{Z}$-basis of $O_K$, so $Disc(O_K\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}_p)$ is the same $\det(Tr(a_ia_l))$ but where $a_i$ can be any $\Bbb{Z}_p$-basis of $O_K\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}_p$).

So it remains to bound $v_p(Disc(O_{K,P_j})$. With $L_j$ the Galois closure of $K_{P_j}/\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $\pi_j$ an uniformizer of $O_{K,P_j}$ and $|O_{K,P_j}/(\pi_j)| =p^{f_j}= N(P_j)$, we have
$$O_{K,P_j}=\Bbb{Z}_p[\alpha_j],\qquad \alpha_j=\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1}+\pi_j$$
$$Disc(O_{K,P_j}) = \prod_{l<m\le [K_{P_j}:\Bbb{Q}_p]} (\sigma_l(\alpha_j)-\sigma_m(\alpha_j))^2$$
(the $\Bbb{Q}_p$-conjugates of $\alpha_j$)

- If $\sigma_l(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1})\ne \sigma_m(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1})$ then $\sigma_l(\alpha_j)-\sigma_m(\alpha_j)\in O_{L_j}^\times$.
- So assume that $\sigma_l(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1}))= \sigma_m(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1})$.

We know that $\pi_j^{e_j}=p u$ with $u\in O_{K,P_j}^\times$ ie. $u=\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1}^r b$ with $b\in 1+\pi_j O_{K,P_j}$.

As $p\ge 5$ and $e_j\le 4$ we have $b^{1/e_j}\in O_{K,P_j}$ and hence $\varpi_j=b^{1/e_j}\pi_j$ is an uniformizer such that $\varpi_j^{e_j}=p \zeta_{p^{f_j}-1}^r$ ie. $\varpi_j^{e_j}=p^{1/e_j}\zeta$ with $\zeta=\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1}^{r/e_j}$ an unramified root of unity.

We can replace the $ \alpha_j=\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1}+\pi_j$ above by $ \alpha_j=\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1}+\varpi_j$.

This lets us treat the case $\sigma_l(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1})= \sigma_m(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1})$ since now we know that $\sigma_l(\alpha_j)=\sigma_l(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1})+p^{1/e_j}\zeta',
\sigma_m(\alpha_j)=\sigma_l(\zeta_{p^{f_j}-1})+p^{1/e_j}\zeta''$ with $\zeta'\ne \zeta''$.

ie. $v_p(\sigma_l(\alpha_j)-\sigma_m(\alpha_j))=1/e_j$ and $$v_p(Disc(O_{K,P_j})) \le \frac{12}{e_j}\le 12$$
$$ v_p(Disc(O_K))\le 48$$

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something, but this seems to be an answer to the other question I asked?

Comment: In fact I don't see any difference in the questions. It is still a quartic number field and you want to bound $v_p(Disc(O_K))$.

Comment: In the first question, I'm trying to bound $v_p(Disc(\mathcal{O}_K))$, and in the second I'm trying to bound $v_p(Disc(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]))$. The second question seems harder to me, since in general $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \neq \mathcal{O}_K$, and they only coincide if the field is monogenic. It seems conceivable to me that $v_p$ of the discriminant of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is bounded but the smallest possible $v_p(Disc(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]))$ is unbounded